# Unable to access Mariadb (Centos 7) with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb, centos7

I have installed `Mariadb` on `Centos 7` and I am trying to access it with `MYSQL Workbench`.

I have done the following:

Start MariaDB execute the following command:

```
 systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Autostart MariaDB execute the following command:

```
 systemctl enable mariadb.service
```

After you started MariaDB (do this only once), execute the following command:

```
  /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

when running this I removed the anonymous user login

We also need to change the port:
    /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf
    # Mariadb network settings

```
[mysqld]
# comment out the bind address
#bind_address=127.0.0.1
```

now I will get an error

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -u root -p mcellblock -h 192.168.159.163 -P 3306
Enter password:
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.159.163' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

I then enabled the connection privileges:

```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mcb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

  MariaDB [mcellblock]> select User, Host, password from mysql.user where Host <> 'localhost';
  +------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
  | User | Host                  | password                                  |
  +------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
  | root | localhost.localdomain | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
  | root | 127.0.0.1             | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
  | root | ::1                   | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
  | root | %                     | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
  | mcb  | %                     | *A071D903A1ABA9752B05C16C573A095C80A7AFAD |
  +------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
  5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now when I try to access via the terminal it works:

```
  $ mysql -u mcb -p mcellblock -h 192.168.159.163 -P 3306
  Enter password:
  Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
  Your MariaDB connection id is 28
  Server version: 5.5.47-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

But when I try to access via MySQL Workbench I get an error:

```
 Please check
  1) Check that mysql is running on server 192.168.159.163  ** IT IS
  2) Check that mysql is running on port 3306 ** I can connect to it via the terminal so I assume it is
  3) Check mcb has the rights to connect to 192.168.159.163 from your address ** It should as its setup for %
  4) Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 192.168.159.163 ** the passwords are the same
```

When I install MySQL Workbench locally it works but not remotely.

**Does anyone know what I am missing or how to trouble shoot this?**

Comment: Check http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,622573,622587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was a firewall issue on the centos machine.  After checking with telnet IP_ADDRESS 3306.  I was unable to access via my other VM nor Windows.  After disabling the firewall it worked.

@Alex I had previously checked the port as well and it was listening correctly.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: If you are not attempting to acess mysqld server from a remote connection, you should not open a port in the firewall.  localhost (127.0.0.1) does not need a firewall port open on 3306 to access mysql.  If you open the port on the firewall you will allow remote access to your mysql server.  That is bad if you don't need to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

If everything you said is correct, it looks more like networking issues, so, please execute:

```
netstat -punta | grep LISTEN
```

Find port being used by mariadb and check if it's something like:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18137/mysqld
```

What really matters here is 3rd column, if you see that, there's one possible problem less, if not, it means that, basically, your mysql server is listening locally.

Keeping on with network issues, it might also be the firewall blocking your connections, so make sure everything is down.

Answer (score 1):

I learned from another similar question (https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux) that inability to connect to mysql can also be due to SELinux.  If you do not have to accesss the mysqld from a remote connection then you should not open a port on the firewall. the   The commands to allow access to MySQL in SEL are:

To check SELinux

```
sestatus
```

To see what flags are set on mysql processes

```
getsebool -a | grep mysql
```

To allow Apache to connect to remote database through SELinux

```
setsebool selinuxuser_mysql_connect_enabled 1
```

Use -P option makes the change permanent. Without this option, the boolean would be reset to 0 at reboot.

```
setsebool -P selinuxuser_mysql_connect_enabled 1
```